# Apportable compilation error with Eventkit

Tags: eventkit, apportable

When trying to compile a Xcode project with Apportable I get a fatal error that the file EventKit/EventKit.h is not found. Is this because EventKit is not supported? Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

EventKit is not available in the Apportable public SDKs. Currently, the best bet is to stub out the references from the app.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. The sad thing is that the whole point of the app is to communicate with the calendar. :(